# GoogleMaps API 2 displays only 1 innerBoundary LinearRing

Tags: api, google-maps, kml, polygon

I have a .kml-file that exists of a polygon which contains an outerBoundary and an innerBoundary. The innerBoundary contains several LinearRings.
Problem: Only one of these inner LinearRings is displayed. The rest is displayed as one big area. Google Earth displays the .kml correctly. Are there any restrictions regarding the us of linearrings in GoogleMaps?

Here is the .kml-content:

```
            <Polygon>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.34937999738613,52.2400931297914,0 10.35028732773128,52.24063618432182,0 10.35073553354421,52.24136351829702,0 10.35189189716032,52.24988592505383,0 10.34806463125521,52.25774091880214,0 10.35510374802005,52.28074093783913,0 10.36525382191662,52.28219923082257,0 10.36640549564265,52.28254037535547,0 10.36735354160269,52.28335789758861,0 10.3674397722104,52.28435970592113,0 10.36663728719742,52.28523389526337,0 10.36519590745014,52.28570827821546,0 10.36391691384635,52.28570033201087,0 10.3517341349819,52.28394646690337,0 10.35051915642555,52.28350569457596,0 10.34978095205181,52.28276776640299,0 10.17123901924045,52.10131997644089,0 10.17235989643872,52.09780217778586,0 10.18052901452957,52.08985594298313,0 10.18354578384427,52.08079068503564,0 10.18637882641355,52.07734629223897,0 10.18854432497935,52.07383155967357,0 10.18955028947235,52.06494065656974,0 10.18692876383424,52.05806110622614,0 10.18609867783059,52.05526279086962,0 10.18266423770521,52.05031096223487,0 10.17496071867752,52.04209487107367,0 10.17296907566858,52.03952206733667,0 10.17149497660236,52.03721517767351,0 10.13695419788886,52.03180553051456,0 10.11185012314924,52.03039116391627,0 10.09087149418022,52.02383748574601,0 10.06395598483749,52.01658923645414,0 10.04264230747145,52.0219364939592,0 10.04127315628253,52.02206100334206,0 9.993582127634355,52.01377847086962,0 9.992518659595907,52.01343413056657,0 9.973070143149375,52.00223345088979,0 9.972452351144421,52.00145279897677,0 9.971465164608219,51.99723807014183,0 9.971729956811503,51.99619487354173,0 9.982781094375952,51.98230833589174,0 9.98584776903783,51.97767128379079,0 9.992498747079996,51.96927237388741,0 9.991526824755352,51.96658410520506,0 9.989677102727526,51.963473925892,0 9.989207353193477,51.95269115440273,0 9.987723808375995,51.94759969646137,0 9.988071290637597,51.94503958871096,0 9.985579149150164,51.92797935885888,0 9.982634581314299,51.92083011116905,0 9.976545113382445,51.91358003449792,0 9.976425347410789,51.91292134538674,0 9.977126572252928,51.90983485754025,0 9.976952152650551,51.9091575821778,0 9.968953361244287,51.90072768735519,0 9.967557385574938,51.89664429777992,0 9.956519186614326,51.89479325501542,0 9.925661213733045,51.88279570915655,0 9.904634577687874,51.87420986179821,0 9.866042836600235,51.87400563077158,0 9.840786680672371,51.86905472152661,0 9.824203687168184,51.86773721822254,0 9.82298684359637,51.86725725891039,0 9.818088684867986,51.86401828583837,0 9.817515015321169,51.86346138336545,0 9.817307929193369,51.86270312498086,0 9.817553956020044,51.86206040887191,0 9.833358727419491,51.83999817325148,0 9.825588568423228,51.82959855222769,0 9.825387811138562,51.82897746283462,0 9.825495834546105,51.82845301933803,0 9.83486681570386,51.80801887912119,0 9.835632705182052,51.80746767536245,0 9.849580942970656,51.80080950671429,0 9.849600167988919,51.78724427692575,0 9.849876463783591,51.78647980124794,0 9.859745265032096,51.77703207261995,0 9.860798037692216,51.77663908436064,0 9.869772750268464,51.77511146307911,0 9.876676533814441,51.75968297256625,0 9.885545467658448,51.75040513318897,0 910.25515643681103,52.19397075429494,0 10.26135026990052,52.21132679490286,0 10.26963559455321,52.23086057113682,0 10.28947890832842,52.23815799379152,0 10.30985734418318,52.23906966294749,0 10.33729401671664,52.23517167118531,0 10.33877755468816,52.23549639900235,0 10.34937999738613,52.2400931297914,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
                <innerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.27240821061489,52.23739156394223,0 10.2764943557397,52.23757524856065,0 10.27174445694194,52.23582825416547,0 10.27240821061489,52.23739156394223,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.18590478472491,52.15184617814074,0 10.18773321261526,52.15414275375152,0 10.21854744180636,52.15686432790342,0 10.23586289911141,52.1616131675119,0 10.22852565174004,52.13471903003445,0 10.19907268145813,52.12880881157728,0 10.19802803146131,52.12843785325227,0 10.19729603908177,52.12787129612924,0 10.18590478472491,52.15184617814074,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.23187520742232,52.13160858695364,0 10.23571535283616,52.1236867447657,0 10.22667121522805,52.11881744802448,0 10.22109857567036,52.11870933547221,0 10.21078352155337,52.11987259654627,0 10.20429452469993,52.11868770269162,0 10.20327487665741,52.11836177245213,0 10.19905835436177,52.11820259075669,0 10.190985760793,52.11586553708817,0 10.20182609048271,52.1255791563385,0 10.23187520742232,52.13160858695364,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.11354864384782,52.02691666973372,0 10.13151211051896,52.02789850744416,0 10.12545920096105,52.02250120742188,0 10.12115370440896,52.02306613120236,0 10.11409090517594,52.02619009189071,0 10.11284926571018,52.02631832329674,0 10.1110575406069,52.02613565645892,0 10.11354864384782,52.02691666973372,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.06289843475212,52.01297237953833,0 10.06368688114465,52.01285424011538,0 10.04400246521565,52.00488379991821,0 10.0351964323982,52.00571428303371,0 10.02573814759202,52.01564941803622,0 10.04137389856296,52.01837271512394,0 10.06289843475212,52.01297237953833,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            10.01882301837729,52.00560126467275,0 10.01791689653521,52.00539276971088,0 10.0050253272684,52.00079801438069,0 9.993875665300854,52.00228244268756,0 9.992134598533912,52.00211352869745,0 9.991166239402519,52.0016318487105,0 9.981427080384554,51.99415622397375,0 9.980941046720865,51.99361138063993,0 9.980759989325868,51.99296427637764,0 9.977359126595832,51.99727356538052,0 9.978038861895602,52.00019420582686,0 9.995846263268103,52.01043639671395,0 10.01994043853371,52.01463901100602,0 10.02777237895539,52.00641389910906,0 10.02626864279406,52.00648239580418,0 10.01882301837729,52.00560126467275,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.855380456437191,51.80169632950742,0 9.855119830069164,51.80243987247973,0 9.854386518894319,51.80305001931052,0 9.839933854203153,51.80995371744533,0 9.831373766045314,51.82878797008037,0 9.839179683205527,51.83922597534188,0 9.839404889927408,51.84029323311771,0 9.823643881550311,51.86242988789854,0 9.826509623369027,51.86432475842264,0 9.842197864125474,51.86555988217815,0 9.86704471096979,51.87044292628841,0 9.905536620020534,51.87061742660831,0 9.906519913254138,51.87072815252332,0 9.928781226163636,51.8797617050511,0 9.959037904887037,51.8915342064961,0 9.968869728798218,51.89293046686156,0 9.977083330120085,51.88675718741706,0 9.982655907636911,51.87820649720261,0 9.984272976389917,51.87138278467505,0 9.983651533434161,51.85353399457469,0 9.987777500110123,51.84763608560537,0 9.981469536990044,51.83274288936134,0 9.970816392727089,51.82703158241299,0 9.956599412741996,51.82907323582232,0 9.95556264347865,51.82910399548598,0 9.921872620678796,51.82237194577901,0 9.91192480770844,51.81694106337533,0 9.906156124476002,51.8115227738887,0 9.891257184341672,51.80867361904743,0 9.890034393182011,51.80820991397683,0 9.889319119927114,51.807439865585,0 9.885811775837659,51.79966617047114,0 9.855391699864116,51.79296879392769,0 9.855380456437191,51.80169632950742,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.86890429376237,51.56354064617938,0 9.869030672132483,51.56708858502184,0 9.868739939008581,51.56780390095923,0 9.864784413676471,51.57056411969143,0 9.863623326635489,51.57115133822988,0 9.859453426883198,51.57483294787452,0 9.857515482579942,51.57850038260351,0 9.854428559135329,51.58106661061861,0 9.854252288034655,51.58298572132568,0 9.854895336189246,51.58473451977891,0 9.862212841963995,51.58982159226014,0 9.869241814810382,51.59244554094607,0 9.871322234564712,51.59363072034962,0 9.881935043226713,51.59871541941715,0 9.882379358832242,51.59929699309934,0 9.88247756305641,51.59983109680827,0 9.881520913538093,51.60604789848786,0 9.889613646059484,51.60130694440697,0 9.890409141381278,51.60108256234895,0 9.895450994668202,51.60040068385107,0 9.903592019914388,51.58728320641903,0 9.905330178839382,51.58167615977795,0 9.907553200849135,51.57969162398687,0 9.906820366259776,51.57871151051718,0 9.903677729334847,51.57595210076617,0 9.89527402192472,51.57357473795214,0 9.890584872936334,51.57287177975935,0 9.881911674694724,51.57035699151297,0 9.876371843174104,51.5656654651476,0 9.869032158747784,51.56107768324107,0 9.86890429376237,51.56354064617938,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.858779201867323,51.489395786305,0 9.864489621937006,51.49867993563625,0 9.867794245523871,51.50340826526058,0 9.873584684187492,51.50883719711155,0 9.874053245703335,51.50967352043285,0 9.873661828012333,51.51074709140966,0 9.871227066916033,51.51264459741823,0 9.865199822266186,51.51417715492575,0 9.860955086576029,51.51640833776862,0 9.859908629441906,51.51873811374746,0 9.858468178311505,51.52096647345068,0 9.857525214583614,51.52373210290834,0 9.857597510748208,51.52418686355039,0 9.859765327686237,51.52715272740425,0 9.862434541871872,51.52767629364014,0 9.865614757326281,51.52852504614184,0 9.866547487939497,51.52789349828291,0 9.867468358529136,51.52755548402293,0 9.874764845725821,51.52679006687561,0 9.875325767065272,51.52638134145568,0 9.874926368670787,51.51820657572394,0 9.87474063387136,51.51651984620041,0 9.874312502754096,51.51545187268457,0 9.874780795333292,51.51327638972658,0 9.874456985777195,51.50921250576209,0 9.874581338154602,51.50603829350691,0 9.873712838338808,51.50455994136525,0 9.873450923529427,51.50306920869146,0 9.873930297392372,51.50181147980375,0 9.875310793678436,51.50076032424005,0 9.881753757897126,51.49869972684076,0 9.880761486319919,51.49754595564943,0 9.88072183859919,51.49684654347324,0 9.881192794667367,51.49523214943569,0 9.876509719819918,51.47837031946511,0 9.850701464793442,51.47583322928328,0 9.847810692240678,51.47478923336729,0 9.858779201867323,51.489395786305,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.700915364420565,51.39833473774542,0 9.704760900917059,51.40249573430605,0 9.717216014224352,51.40815082334107,0 9.726732623236611,51.4074530351857,0 9.722770449280167,51.40476707154078,0 9.720262729350688,51.40032684898068,0 9.710957776498663,51.39567950127049,0 9.709086330617494,51.39579774654011,0 9.707890707395132,51.39562598075706,0 9.705084177996804,51.39438960270704,0 9.70354585738661,51.39348123887451,0 9.700915364420565,51.39833473774542,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.698936529761641,51.39078538267555,0 9.677762021304144,51.3787958120418,0 9.677008755773104,51.38211581122835,0 9.682988923925883,51.39053067020733,0 9.693828612498157,51.39614277114144,0 9.695244796747653,51.39759564779137,0 9.698936529761641,51.39078538267555,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.522034625765256,51.22259437450317,0 9.522979205800814,51.22370380330301,0 9.52768334312384,51.22746450172978,0 9.53635605519032,51.21216414973087,0 9.525539137183376,51.18814702076687,0 9.525399410194455,51.18823971302789,0 9.527310124965183,51.19501998921333,0 9.528298630294144,51.2057504581035,0 9.53204252703279,51.20828155732802,0 9.532498594287013,51.20889328602176,0 9.53258073147564,51.20945485152588,0 9.532213525360746,51.21290572972887,0 9.531910321718831,51.21351406586848,0 9.522034625765256,51.22259437450317,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.526567184112189,51.21207137148459,0 9.526785168010123,51.20999667128658,0 9.523291568868128,51.20764874799909,0 9.522685878292876,51.20683386405892,0 9.521605113535721,51.195334894947,0 9.520211295082605,51.19043984922755,0 9.510266683134566,51.19385765700603,0 9.509463336935815,51.1968992424458,0 9.501356257893827,51.20709698936993,0 9.502119168542613,51.21478809659912,0 9.512304662533206,51.21897404368077,0 9.518206492157084,51.21973903684739,0 9.526567184112189,51.21207137148459,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.566525360512614,50.95188995013688,0 9.565479242591346,50.95449309176134,0 9.564802800709609,50.96003377443925,0 9.567534207392471,50.96226322842058,0 9.569698398842194,50.96456983453521,0 9.575536280129162,50.96928088347298,0 9.576055653035635,50.96995108744741,0 9.576277222243927,50.98296415481611,0 9.579364036175264,50.99277703000576,0 9.582533132190738,50.99138605706582,0 9.584352635304223,50.98904585067294,0 9.58581067352212,50.98790619940409,0 9.596392328911248,50.98394786818935,0 9.598667153104369,50.9821897573667,0 9.603232195633218,50.97945012627671,0 9.614428236192232,50.97561718875059,0 9.644160337633387,50.96635515847068,0 9.65028951030282,50.96171054751159,0 9.654237948243322,50.95754130345146,0 9.657791683275045,50.95480841775315,0 9.658940270915299,50.95208128446779,0 9.661390326838658,50.94728570709903,0 9.666505042348,50.94150469916001,0 9.65936931086183,50.93930120802193,0 9.640094527498892,50.93882642485261,0 9.635736252370434,50.93973613853624,0 9.610687192073122,50.94005363827884,0 9.59376008313339,50.94328774217297,0 9.582192203629981,50.94160152758662,0 9.577345136066558,50.9453347954319,0 9.574690150351453,50.94820249070614,0 9.566525360512614,50.95188995013688,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.691035727400973,50.94291153857649,0 9.689766324329076,50.94351462196823,0 9.688500981213201,50.94388586575064,0 9.683879870931593,50.94453884540298,0 9.679208397988028,50.94685105621964,0 9.677416907750475,50.94752801006935,0 9.674552236791667,50.95076797113131,0 9.67255599884742,50.9547103928351,0 9.671032377865732,50.9583296873603,0 9.670467991921349,50.95913579865325,0 9.666016990148759,50.96261560124843,0 9.661791337571643,50.96703634982091,0 9.655006719562683,50.97218451816755,0 9.651705894600344,50.97792265148249,0 9.693756857659995,50.96115383024377,0 9.692363174997794,50.94211981725465,0 9.691035727400973,50.94291153857649,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.705487811251786,50.950975535479,0 9.738264711641767,50.92250707407628,0 9.737719884122978,50.91949528507026,0 9.732327895099079,50.92016993985099,0 9.704071088296358,50.93243878579288,0 9.705487811251786,50.950975535479,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.57297933239772,50.9401935460989,0 9.568953345788223,50.9399725935024,0 9.556408846647523,50.94562492276181,0 9.558357888420554,50.95029368366789,0 9.558936040330554,50.94908033246935,0 9.55982348096966,50.94831011477817,0 9.568323611436394,50.94450353082688,0 9.570261536638659,50.94230436055462,0 9.57297933239772,50.9401935460989,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </innerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
```

Comment: How did you create this kml file?  What do you expect it to look like?  It looks to me like this point in the outer boundary is incorrect "910.25515643681103,52.19397075429494,0"

Comment: btw, V2 is deprecated and could be shut off as early as May so you should consider upgrading to V3.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the integrity of your [kml](http://www.tennettso.de/site/binaries/content/assets/netzausbau/karten/neustekarte.kml) file. There are a couple of problems:

1. The `xsi` prefix declaration is missing:

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
2. Once I added that, the [Galdos KML validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) was able to process the file.

   Here's what it told me:

   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'LinearRing'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":BoundarySimpleExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":BoundaryObjectExtensionGroup}' is expected.

   (My desktop XML validator issued the same complaint.)

The problem is that `<kml:innerBoundaryIs>` contains multiple `<kml:LinearRing>` elements.

Then, checking the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#innerboundaryis) for `<kml:innerBoundaryIs>` I found this:

*Contains a <LinearRing> element. A Polygon can contain multiple <innerBoundaryIs>
elements, which create multiple cut-outs inside the Polygon.*

So, it appears that Google Earth may be tolerant of your malformed KML, but perhaps Google Maps is not.

**Possible solution**: Instead of repeating `<kml:LinearRing>` within `<kml:innerBoundaryIs>`, try repeating `<kml:innerBoundaryIs>` within `<kml:Polygon>`.

Comment: Glad to hear that I was able to help. The custom is to **accept the answer**...see [How does excepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). By doing so, you'll draw attention to the solution that worked for you, the author of the answer is rewarded and even you the question asker pick up a couple of points.

Comment: @user1611663, you might also consider **up-voting** this answer as well...see [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the LinearRing polylines are crossing themselves.

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linkto.html?lat=52.051462&lng=10.031042&zoom=9&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/testkml_polygon_inner_kml.xml

There is some character encoding issue which makes the chrome browser fail on the kml, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

It looks like a problem with the Google Maps KML renderer (although I suppose it could be a problem with the KML), geoxml3 renders it correctly, but KmlLayer does not:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linkto.html?lat=52.051462&lng=10.031042&zoom=9&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/neustekarteA_kml.xml

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.tennettso.de%2Fsite%2Fbinaries%2Fcontent%2Fassets%2Fnetzausbau%2Fkarten%2Fneustekarte.kml&hl=en&sll=51.600305,9.931552&sspn=2.043772,3.532104&t=m&z=8) renders it the same as KmlLayer:

There are [limitations on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport), but it doesn't look like you are running in to them.

Probably should [open an issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) against the KML renderer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.
I make it a bit more precise.

Here is the map with the overlay:
http://www.tennettso.de/site/binaries/content/assets/netzausbau/karten/trassewahlemecklar.html

if you put the .kml in google earth the filled areas are not filled.(like in the part bottom-left next to the city "Neuenstein") Why is googlemaps not displaying it correctly? Are there any limitations?